# Remote repo filename has different case than local, but no change seen

Tags: git, gitlab, case-sensitive

When I browse to the directory containing a particular file in gitlab, I see `TimeHhMM.cs` (with the second "M" capitalized).

But in my local repo, the file is `TimeHhMm.cs` (with the second "m" lower case).

Strangely enough, git does not see this as a change worthy of making it into a commit. Occasionally, some weirdness does pop up that shows there is a problem, though. I just recloned from the origin repo and through a remote pointing to my local filesystem, brought in the branches from my old local repo. `git status` then showed `TimeHhMM.cs` deleted--but no `TimeHhMm.cs` was added. When I discard the deletion and rename the file to the appropriate `TimeHhMm.cs`, *git sees no differences to commit*.

That's really weird. Why would it on the one hand detect the file was deleted (case sensitively) but as soon as I bring it back and rename it, it can't detect the "new" file with the lower case "m"?

I can fix this by deleting the file then re-adding it in two separate commits, but it seems there should be some way to cause this action to occur in a single commit. Is there one?

Comment: What system are you doing this from?  That is, are you on a case-sensitive file-system?  or does core.ignorecase happen to be set to true?  (Test with `git config core.ignorecase`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior is controlled by `core.ignoreCase` variable. Quoting [the docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> If `true`, this option enables various workarounds to enable Git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like FAT. For
>   example, if a directory listing finds `"makefile"` when Git expects
>   `"Makefile"`, Git will assume it is really the same file, and continue
>   to remember it as `"Makefile"`.
>
> The default is `false`, **except `git-clone` or `git-init` will probe and set `core.ignoreCase true` if appropriate when the repository is created**.

And that was probably the case. You can always reset it to `false` with the following command:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

---

This (quite old) [forum thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Why-don-t-git-init-and-git-clone-probe-for-core-ignorecase-on-Windows-gt-XP-td5900337.html) sheds some light on how exactly probing is done:

> As far as I can tell from the code (I obviously only look at the plain
>   vanilla git, and `msysgit` might have some patch to this part, I dunno. 
>   Oh by the way you didn't say which version you are complaining about,
>   either), we do the probing on all systems (including POSIX folks with
>   FAT filesystem mounted) by first creating `.git/config` and then
>   checking if a file `.git/CoNfIg` which we know we never created can be
>   accessed.  If we can, that means the filesystem ignores case, iow, we
>   cannot have two files `config` and `CoNfIg` at the same time, and set
>   `core.ignorecase` to true.

Comment: Yes, that fixes it. Is the `core.ignorecase=true` setting the default or something? It seems nonsensical. I deleted this setting from my local config and added `core.ignorecase=false` to my global config.

Comment: How does git determine if it is "appropriate when the repository is created"?

Comment: Updated the answer with details. )